# how to rollback committed data in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, rollback

by mistake i have updated my table without any condition like `update mytable set status = 1` and all row of my table got updated.
Can committed data be rolled back in `SQL Server`? If yes then how can we do this. Please help.

Comment: what backup strategy are you using ?

Comment: You can use your last backup.

Comment: No - once committed, data **cannot** be rolled back anymore. You'll need to either undo your transaction, or restore a backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i have to do is restore backup nothing else.